# What exactly does the File's Owner and First Responder Placeholder in Xcode represent

Tags: ios, iphone

What exactly does the File's Owner and First Responder Placeholder in X code represent.can any one describe here in details and how to use it when we developing application.

Comment: please read an introductory book about iOS app development! -1

Comment: I want few practically example

Comment: He is right ,apple doc is to technically to understand for beginner..

Comment: it's more confusing ..

Comment: not satisfy and understand with above ans..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The File owner is the object that loads the nib . Ie. that object
   which receives the message loadNib Named: or initWithNibName: .
2. So if you want to access any objects in the nib from the object after
   loading it , you set an outlet to the the file owner .